# Jquery/JavaScript runs locally, but not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I made a PHP form that has jquery inside, for input mask and a Postal code search.

On my local machine, it runs fine. But once i send to my server via FTP, it doesn't.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/0.9.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? And is there a test page you can point us to?

Comment: first Load Jquery Lib (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`)then all others....

Comment: here it is https://ssl5929.websiteseguro.com/sbpsp2/psicorreio/emailmarketing/2015/teste/ficha_inscricao.php

Comment: Thank You guys ! solved the mask problem

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript must be loaded first, and with the site you listed, I can see that the http (cloudflare) should be https ...

Try ...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/0.9.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the error on the `http`:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://ssl5929.websiteseguro.com/sbpsp2/psicorreio/emailmarketing/2015/teste/ficha_inscricao.php'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/0.9.0/jquery.mask.min.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: It solved that problem! but now i got other...
i can't change the postal code(CEP field) POST http to https... if i do that, it doesn't work... if i don't... i doesn't work too (Can see on the console that got blocked for not being https)

Comment: Ummm ... I can think of two possibilities.  The easiest, put the file on your server and access it locally.  The hard way, track down a CDN where it can be accessed via https ...

Comment: It's not even the cloudflare link... in line 67 i create a variable to use as JSON request...

Comment: That sounds like a different question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
>   Line 6

Error Says **JavaScript requires jQuery**

So you Need to run Jquery First

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/0.9.0/jquery.mask.min.js">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
```